# Ruta base en Flask es necesaria?

Tags: python, flask, rutas

Tengo este codigo que redirige a una ruta localhost:5000/hello/nombre y luego se le agrega la edad, para que luego retorne la informacion del nombre,=o ambos si son introducidas en la ruta

```
@app.route("/hello/")
@app.route("/hello/<string:nombre>")
@app.route("/hello/<string:nombre>/<int:edad>")
def hola(nombre=None,edad=None):
    if nombre and edad:
        return 'Hola, {0} tienes {1} años.'.format(nombre,edad)
    elif nombre:
        return 'Hola, {0}'.format(nombre)
    else:
        return 'Hola mundo'
```

mi duda es por que se escribe:

```
@app.route("/hello/")
```

en vez de colocarla completa

```
@app.route("/hello/<string:nombre>/<int:edad>")
```

hay alguna razon para escribirla asi?

Ademas que significa poner None como valor como default en las variables?

Comment: Cada decorador es una ruta diferente, si solo colocas `@app.route("/hello/<string:nombre>/<int:edad>")` entonces flask solo retornará cuando la ruta cumpla con ese patrón, más no con `/hello`.

Comment: Ah okey, o sea que tengo 3 rutas diferentes, una sola con hello, una con el nombre y otro con el nombre y la edad y la funcion hola se ejecutara en esas 3 rutas y dependiendo de los parametros que tenga retornara lo que la condicion diga. no? @Christian

Comment: otra cosa cuando en la funcion en las variables le da el valor de None, que significa eso? @Christian

Comment: Pues sip, esas 3 rutas tienen asociadas una misma función. En cuanto al `None` es simplemente un valor que se le da al parámetro, ya que a veces no se especifican todos los parámetros y por ello se le da un valor por defecto, ya que sino dará error

Comment: A okey pero igual lo podria dejar sin ningun valor tipo def hola(nombre, edad) no seria lo mismo o hay alguna diferencia? @Christian

Comment: Sí, hay diferencia. Si no especificas un valor por defecto entonces para la primera ruta la función se llamará de esta forma `hola()` lo que dará error ya que la función espera 2 argumentos y para el segundo caso será llamada `hola(nombre="algun_nombre")` lo que también dará error, ya que no se han pasado esos 2 parámetros y son obligatorios. Pero al poner en la declaración `def hola(nombre=None, edad=None)` le dices a python que en caso el parámetro no sea pasado tomará el valor de `None`

Comment: no entendi mucho @Christian